# Extract Street Address without Numbered Street Names

Tags: python, regex, openstreetmap

I'm trying to extract the street number from addresses such as this:

```
1520 32nd Street
3215 Sheldon Rd
```

But replacing not digits, gets the 32 out the first.

```
python>  re.sub(r'\D', '', street)
152032
3215
```

I'm pretty sure I need a negative look around, but I can't get it right.

Comment: You're trying to extract, or replace? Two different things

Comment: Extract,  I want 1520  3215,  but not 32nd

Comment: Way to few information about your input data. According to your two very simple examples you could just use `split()[0]`.

Comment: Also, where does your input come from? Your question has the #openstreetmap tag. However in OSM addresses are composed of several parts, i.e. *not* a single string. Therefore depending on your use-case working with raw OSM data could be easier since you don't have to perform any magic for detecting address formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your task would be easier if you were first to engage in the process of *address normalization*: converting addresses into a standard format with well-defined fields.  There are various tools out there for doing this; the [`usaddress`](https://github.com/datamade/usaddress) module seems to work well for US addresses.

```
>>> import usaddress
>>> addr = usaddress.tag('1520 32nd St')
>>> addr[0]['AddressNumber']
'1520'
```

And for your second address:

```
>>> addr = usaddress.tag('3215 Sheldon Rd')
>>> addr[0]['AddressNumber']
'3215'
```